# Better way to scrape for time sensitive information?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, web-scraping, phantomjs

Right now what I been doing is using setting an interval to look for an changes. If there are any changes my script will alert me and if there isn't it will wait one second and then check again. Is there a better way to do this? The information my script is looking for is time sensitive so if the script alerts me too slow I will won't be able to do anything with the information. So what's I'm asking is there a better approach so I can be alert of any changes as soon as it happens?

Code:

```
page.open(url)
timer = Date.now();
do{
if(Date.now()-timer>=1000){
//Look for change
}
timer =Date.now()
}while (no chnages)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhantomJS doesn't work well when using a synchronous loop as in your case. Since JavaScript is single-threaded, this will block execution.

## With Delay

You can certainly use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` for this case:

```
var interval = 1000; // change according to needs
page.open(url, function(){
    setTimeout(function retry(){
        var condition = page.evaluate(...);
        if (!condition) {
            setTimeout(retry, interval);
        } else {
            // TODO: what to do on success
        }
    }, interval);
});
```

The `setInterval` example would look similarly. In fact, that's what [`waitFor()`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) does in the examples folder of PhantomJS. The problem with these approaches is of course a possible delay between the change and a notification of that change. You can of course decrease retry interval until you don't see any difference anymore.

## Without Delay

There are at least two ways to detect a change without delay.

- Register to the [`page.onResourceReceived` event](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-received.html) and try to determine whether the change that you're interested in has happened with the limited information provided (it's not possible to look into the body of the request).
- In PhantomJS 2.x (in 1.x possibly with a prefix), you can create a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to look for changes in the DOM in the page context (in [`page.evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html)) and then you send an immediate notification from the page context (from the MutationObserver event handler) to the outer context using the [`window.callPhantom` and `page.onCallback` pair](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-callback.html).

Answer (score 1):

If the resource you're fetching is setting the last modified header correctly, it *could* be more efficient to make a HTTP HEAD request first, and only open the page in PhantomJS if it has been modified. This would definitely be more complex, so it would be worth checking out other options first.

Some sample code which checks last modification time on http://stackoverflow.com is as follows.

```
var url = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
var page = require('webpage').create();
var interval = 1000; // change according to needs
var previousLastModified;
(function modifiedCheck() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var lastModified = xhr.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified");
            if (lastModified !== previousLastModified) {
                page.open(url, function(status) {
                    if (status === 'success') {
                        previousLastModified = lastModified;
                        // TODO: do something with fetched page
                        console.log('fetched page.');
                    }
                    setTimeout(modifiedCheck, interval);
                });
            } else {
                setTimeout(modifiedCheck, interval);
            }
        }
    };
    console.log('making HEAD request.');
    xhr.open('HEAD', url);
    xhr.send();
})();
```

You can see from the console logging that the page is cached for 1 minute.

The self-executing `modifiedCheck` function in the example uses anonymous functions to asynchronously process both the result of the AJAX call and the PhantomJS page load, thus limiting blocking.

Note you need to run PhantomJS with the `--web-security=false` option to allow the AJAX call to execute without error.